# Twitter Cards - No Meta tags found but Twitter and Open Graph meta tags are clearly visible in the source file

Tags: twitter

I am trying to share this url https://qaweb.unation.dev/event/Visit-to-Raleigh-544016631 on twitter. But twitter cards are not being previewed.

I have added all the twitter and open graph meta tags in the source file and that are clearly visible in the source file but twitter validator says that no meta tags found. Then i came to know that twitterbot should be allowed to all in the robots.txt file and i implemented that as well but no success so far.

Following is the screenshot of the source file that assures that all the meta tags have been added and exists in the source file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEt4e.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P11wC.png)

Comment: Curl returns 401 Auth required. So the Twitter crawler cannot check it. That’s literally why Twitter troubleshooting doc requires a url. Did you read the Twitter checklist?

Comment: Also, please do not post screenshots of StackOverflow, they don’t get indexed and are impossible to debug.

Comment: Both of the URLs in the screenshots are different to what you’ve shared in the post and none of them are publicy accessible. Have you checked the Twitter card troubleshooting docs?

Comment: There is literally no way to validate your meta tags since your URL is inaccessible.

Comment: @AndyPiper url is publicly accessible now.

Comment: There is no `twitter:title` or `og:title` tag specified (at least one of these are required). Also, all of the `twitter:app:*` tags are not useful for a Summary Large Image card, they only apply to an app card, so none of these will be used anyway.

Comment: @AndyPiper Issue was not related to these tags. Issue was in the robots.txt file that i had made twitter bot disabled that's why twitter bot was unable to crawl the meta tags to show twitter card.Moreover, twitter:title and og:title meta tags have been added and clearly visible in the page.